# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to move checked checkboxes from one checklist, which is actually in a table, to another checklist in another table so the two are in sync. However, this code gives me the syntax error "Unexpected end of input" in Chrome and won't work:

```js
var checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.contentChecks');
var chkArray = [];
chkArray = $.map(checkedBoxes, function(el) {
  if(el.checked) { return el.id.substring(1, el.id.length) }
});

for (var i = 0; i < chkArray.length; i++)
{
  var checkbox = document.getElementById("B" + chkArray[i]);
  checkbox.checked = true;
  var row = $("#B" + chkArray[i]).closest('tr'); // row with changed checkbox
  row.insertBefore(row.parent().find('tr:first-child')); // move to top
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Checkboxes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="checkbox" id="A127" class="contentChecks" checked />
         <label for="A127" class="todo">
           &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-check"></i>Sample Text 1
         </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="checkbox" id="A32" class="contentChecks" checked />
         <label for="A32" class="todo">
           &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-check"></i>Sample Text 2
         </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="checkbox" id="A1543" class="contentChecks" checked />
         <label for="A1543" class="todo">
           &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-check"></i>Sample Text 3
         </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 
 <table id="table2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Checkboxes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="checkbox" id="B127" class="contentChecks2" />
         <label for="B127" class="todo">
           &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-check"></i>Sample Text 1
         </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="checkbox" id="B32" class="contentChecks2" />
         <label for="B32" class="todo">
           &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-check"></i>Sample Text 2
         </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="checkbox" id="B1543" class="contentChecks2" />
         <label for="B1543" class="todo">
           &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-check"></i>Sample Text 3
         </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

I've tried debugging this a million ways to no avail, except I have concluded that something must be wrong with my for loop since commenting out the other code still gave the error. I've put this code in JavaScript validators and they all conclude the syntax is valid and the "end of the input" is just fine. Also it works just fine in my code snippet.

**IMPORTANT:** I am pulling this JavaScript code from an external file, so it is HTML along with this JS being returned from an AJAX call to the webpage the user is seeing, replacing the previous HTML.

Comment: When you say "in Chrome", it means that all other browsers the code is ok and no errors appears?
Also, could you create a snippet as a [mcve] ?

Comment: @CalvinNunes I've tried it in IE and Edge and the code still doesn't work, but no console errors are thrown. Also I've read much documentation that this may be a Chrome-specific issue. A code snippet is on the way.

Comment: @MaxVoisard you have an extra/unnecessary semi-colon after your if statement - remove it and see if the syntax error still occurs?

Comment: @RachelGallen Thanks, but no luck.

Comment: @MaxVoisard oh well. It was still extraneous...

Comment: Well code here has no error when it is run so what is different?

Comment: @epascarello Read the last sentence I just added to the question - I think it has to do with loading scripts in AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - it was a **scope** issue. Trying to pull HTML and JavaScript from an external file didn't work on the AJAX call, so I just put the same code under the `complete` section of the AJAX call of the same file/page and it worked :)